# Easiest way to search for a directory or a file in UNIX?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

What's the easiest command to use to search for a directory or file containing "abc" in it?

Comment: Step one: clarify what you want.  Do you want a file whose name contains the string 'abc', or whose contents contains 'abc', or whose contents is exactly 'abc'?  Do you want a directory whose name contains 'abc', or a directory that contains a file named 'abc', or a directory that contains a file with 'abc' in its content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command:

```
find . -name "*abc*"
```

The previous command will search for any file or directory containing "abc" within the current directory (and all its subdirectories).

Answer (score 1):

The [locate](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate%201) command

```
locate "*abc*"
```

also works in addition to the [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) command already mentioned.

Note, this works *quickly* by querying a database created/updated/maintained by the `updatedb` command which usually runs regularly as a cron job. This means however that if the file was just created you may not find it until `updatedb` runs again (or you run it yourself assuming you have sudo priviledges). In those circumstances `find` might be your best bet, while slower, as it searches the directories you specify right at that moment.

Comment: This is much faster but requires the file is in a location indexed by updatedb.

Comment: @jordanm that is correct, on most (all?) systems I've worked on this job (updatedb) runs regularly as a cron job, but it may be a good idea to mention this. Thanks for reminding me, I'll add a note.

Comment: I am actually on Gow, so that command doesn't work. But thanks! I will try it out on a linux box sometime

Comment: What about grep or sed? What do those do? I have seen some people use them for some kind of searching?

Comment: @antonpug both are very useful, but usually work with file. `grep` will search for strings in files, .e.g, `grep apple *.txt` will search for the string `apple` in all files ending with the name `.txt`. `sed` is a stream editor, it allows you to search through files and edit them without having to invoked an editor. Both worth knowing, along wtth `awk`, also a tool for processing files (one of my favorites).

Comment: Gow is GNU On Windows :) https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/

Comment: @antonpug Ah .. thanks for the info, I knew about Cygwin but hadn't heard about this. Odd that it wouldn't have `locate`, it's not a very "exotic" command :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
find / -iname "*abc*"
```